# bootstrap.js Accordion Active Index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to retrieve the active index so that I can use previous / next buttons, and also error check the form values in each stage of the accordion.

Is there a way to get the active index of the accordion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var index = $('#accordion .in').parent().index();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the accordion-group that is a accordion item, using that:

```
var accordionItem = $('.accordion .accordion-body.in:first').parents('.accordion-group');
```

Now you can get the index of accordionItem.