# bootstrap accordion how to check which panel is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am using Bootstrap's accordion widget to contain several forms i.e. each panel contains one form. When the last panel is selected, the data from the other panels is meant to be posted which will be used to graph the data. However, I am unable to get to the posting part as I cannot figure out which panel is currently selected.  I know that this has to do with a class of active or inactive, but I don't think bootstrap's accordion supports that functionality unlike jquery accordion.

I am trying to figure out the first part i.e. check if the user has clicked on the last panel. In my HTML code it has an id of #results. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4thcu/) that demonstrates the issue I am facing. It does not seem to trigger the second alert function when the user clicks on the #results tag, not sure why.

Sample javascript code:

```
 $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#results').click(function () {
        alert("works"); //testing purposes
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap.js Accordion Active Index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695725/bootstrap-js-accordion-active-index)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

**Fiddle:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/4thcu/1/)

take this outside the on function

```
 $('#results').click(function (){
        alert("clicked");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do?

```
$('#results').click(function (){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Just remove the accordion function and you'll get the on click event directly

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I wanted to post an answer as the expected result is not suggested.

What you need to do here is to handle the currently selected collapse items with the event handler. If you use the `this` keyword for this, you can access the values of the selected object (For example only one item in the form).

Here you can get the `$(".collapse")` element.
You can get the `index` number of the active item with `$(this).parent().index()`.
Likewise, you can get the `id` of the active item with `$(this).attr('id')`.

Your jQuery structure would be:

```
$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(){

 //0,1,2,etc..
 var index = $(this).parent().index();
 
 //collapseOne, collapseTwo, etc..
 var id =  $(this).attr('id')
 
 //alert('Index: ' + index + '\nItem Id: ' + id );
 console.log('Index: ' + index)
 console.log('Item Id: ' + id)
  
 if(id === 'collapseFour')
 {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();
        
    //here you can check the data from the form
    
        $("#result").html("<p> UserName: " + username + "</p> <p> EMail: " + email + "</p> <p> Age: " + age + "</p>");
 }
});
```

I've included a working example here for you ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbgurcan/r4v3u6xo/48/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (accordion) {
    var $activeCard = $(accordion.delegateTarget.children);
});
```

or

```
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    var $activeCard = $(this.children);
});
```